# can't read mongodb data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**save:**

```
   var pageListSchema = new Schema({
    pid:String,
    name:String,
    eName:String,
    pages:[{name:String,id:String,type:String}]
    });
    var pageList = db.model('pageList',pageListSchema);
    var p = new pageList({pid:getId,name:getName,eName:getEName,pages:[{name:"html",id:"0",type:"0"}]});
    p.save();
```

**read:**

```
pageList.find({pages:[{id:"0"}]},function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
pageList.find({pages:{$elemMatch:{id:"0"}}},function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

**result:**

```
[ { _pid: '510a3e793f30c5980f000001'
name: 'cc',
eName: 'cc',
_id: 510a3e803f30c5980f000002,
__v: 0,
pages: [ '[object Object]' ] } ]
```

there are two method of read data,but why I got a string rather than a object

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  If you do console.log(data[0].pages[0]) what does that return?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` calls [`util.inpsect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) to format your passed `data` object into a string.  That method only recurses two levels deep into objects, by default, so the contents of `pages` elements aren't formatted.

To get full output for all levels of `data`:

```
console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
```